# Google analytics cookie

Tags: java, cookies, google-analytics, analytics

hi i to am develop a web application that needs to maintain a persistent connection through cookie methods, but when i retrieve the cookie from the server and explore the cookie it doesn't seem to be the original one with the text generated by ga.js JavaScript.
the web application is on client side, there is a way that i can execute the JavaScript when I download the page to match the original cookie like a web browser?

Thx.

Comment: The cookie set by Google Analytics and the session-persistence cookies set by your app are completely separate, and they have nothing to do with each other. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i am tryng to send the cookie requested by the server and the cookie generated by the ga.js that is on the page that i downloaded, i have see the prime of the HTTPCLIENT to resolve this problem and apparently i have to use some JAVAScript engine to execute the javaScript on the Fly,That is something new to me.....

Comment: i think that is executing the script with a javaScript engine in the context of the page and then setting the reqest body with a javaScript alrready executed

Comment: finally i have to use WebKit toolkit in a Qt enviroment.